# Use a function that was passed by props and is not associated with a given event as a click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

Good morning community, I have a question. I am working with react js and I have to pass a function through props to a child component. The question is that this function is not going to be directly associated with a click, but I must use it but applying some logic in the child component and in case the condition is fulfilled launching said function passed by props. Can what I say be done or always the function that passes by itself must be associated with an arrow function and a given event?

```
export default father extends Component{
    const fun = () => {
      console.log("hello")
    }

  render(){
   return(
    <Child fun = {this.fun} />
   )
  }

export default child extends Component{
    this.state = {
        count : 1
    }
    const thing = () => {
        const { count } = this.state
        if(count == 1){
            this.props.fun
        }else{
            console.log("is not 1")
        }
    }
    render(){
      return(
        <Button onPress = {() => this.thing()} />
     )
   }
}
```

It's a pretty bad example but it's something similar to what I want to do

Comment: Have you tried it? When you pass a function down, it's just passed down like any other object. There's no special requirement that functions passed in props need to be event handlers. You're free to call it wherever you want.

Comment: Show some code, what you have done so far? How I can get an idea, what are you doing wrong

Comment: You need to ensure you call the function `this.props.fun()` in `thing` otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: How could I make sure to call her, excuse me for the silly question

Comment: `this.props.fun` is not how you call a function. That just... gets the value of the variable, which is a reference to a function, and then does nothing with it. To call a function, you put `()` after it (possibly with arguments inside the parentheses). So `this.props.fun()` is what you want, not `this.props.fun`. I think maybe you should take a step back and learn a bit about plain JavaScript before diving into React.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have written can be done. The function that you pass down as props can be executed conditionally, as an event handler, or not at all. Once you pass it as props it is completely up to you how you want to use it.

Comment: @ivanzapata Where is the example?

Comment: I just added it to the question

Comment: Yeah, I mean the syntax is all over the place, but yes that would work.

Comment: This is something similar to what I have but I would not be throwing the function in the child component ... I check the props and the function exists as such within the child component but without compromise when I use it in the way that is in the example no It runs. However, when I use it immediately on the button onPress if it works ...

Comment: @ivanzapata Can you double check your comment? I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry! Please be aware, you will need to invoke the call of `this.props.fun` by adding `()` like this: `this.props.fun()`.